# Referencing Elements of Class Vectors using C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, object, vector

I am trying to switch the elements of a class vector using pointers.  I am not using this method simply to solve a small problem, but just to practice using this method for more difficult problems.

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class thing{
    public:
        int index;
        int value;
        thing();
    private: int number;

};
thing::thing()
{
    number = 0;
}
void arrange(vector<thing>* array[]){
    for(int i=0; i<19; ++i){
        if(array[i]->value<array[i+1]->value){
            swap(array[i], array[i+1]);
            arrange(array);
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    vector<thing>** things = new thing*[20];
    for (int i=0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        things[i] = new thing();  // default constructor
        things[i]->index = i;
        things[i]->value=rand() % 100;
    }
    cout << "The random array is: " << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<20;++i){
        cout << things[i]->value << endl;
    }
    arrange(*things);
    cout << "The arranged array is: " << endl;
    for (int i=0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        cout << things[i]->value << endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: A more sane question is **why**. a pointer to a pointer of a vector? *shudder*, there are so many better way you could solve this issue.

Comment: Just practice. Also, I think using this method uses less memory.

Comment: DON'T mix vectors and manually-allocated dynamic arrays. You get the worst of both worlds.

Comment: What problem are you having? All you've told us is what you're trying to do.

Comment: `vector<thing>* array[]` My brain exploded trying to parse that line.

Comment: no it doesn't. you shouldn't try to write C++ in a (poor) C-ish style

Comment: You should usually ask a question on SO...

Comment: I did't see any questions in your post.

Comment: void arrange(vector<thing>* array[]){
    for(int i=0; i<19; ++i){
        if(array[i]->value<array[i+1]->value){

Comment: the problem is in the for loop of the function.. It says no member named value in std...

Comment: That's because you have `array[i]->value`, and `array` is an array of pointers to vectors... you're indexing to a specific `vector` in the array, but not a specific element in the `vector`.  You probably want to pass the `vector` by reference instead of by pointer (i.e. `void arrange(std::vector<thing>& array)`) but I haven't looked at your program overall to see if that creates other problems.  Anyway, ***explain your problem in your question***, not just in the comments here....

Comment: there is no array. it's just a vector that I named array bc I was first doing this problem with arrays and now I want to do it with vectors

Comment: sorry, I don't see an edit button for the name of the question

Comment: @JCoder... `* array[]` means the function is still expecting an array....

Comment: thank you. Chiron's updated code works, but only to output the random vector. The arrange function stalls and there is no further output. If someone could take a look at where a loop or memory leak may be occurring that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class thing{
    public:
    int index;
    int value;
    thing();
    private: int number;

};
thing::thing()
{
    number = 0;
}
// This arrange accept array of any length
void arrange(vector<thing *> &array)
{
    while(1)
    {
        int regressed=1;
        for(int i=0; i<array.size()-1; i++){
        if( (array[i]->value) < (array[i+1]->value) ){
            thing * tmp=array[i+1];
            array[i+1]=array[i];
            array[i]=tmp;
            regressed=0;
        }
        }
        if(regressed==1)
            return;
        }
}
int main(){
    vector<thing*> things; // init a container to contain " thing * " type vars
    for (int i=0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
    thing * t = new thing();  // default constructor
    t->index = i;
    t->value=rand() % 100;
    things.push_back(t);      // Add vars appended
    }
    cout << "The random array is: " << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<20;++i){
    cout << things[i]->value << endl;
    }
    arrange(things);
    cout << "The arranged array is: " << endl;
    for (int i=0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
    cout << things[i]->value << endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

The result output is :

```
The random array is: 
83
86
77
15
93
35
86
92
49
21
62
27
90
59
63
26
40
26
72
36
The arranged array is: 
93
92
90
86
86
83
77
72
63
62
59
49
40
36
35
27
26
26
21
15
```

Remember that:

```
vector<int> varname;
vector<int *> varname;
```

has the same logical meaning as:

```
int varname[size];
int* varname[size];
```

but vectors can be expanded automatically when you add new elements into it:

```
vectVar.push_back(sth);
```

Reading some docs about vector's usage first would be helpful enough.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want, thank you. But second part is not working The arrange function does not work, and the program stalls. Is it maybe an infinite loop? The output is as you show, but no output for an arranged array.

Comment: I've updated the answer for your confusions. Please check it above if you see this reply

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved everything. The only change I made was to       thing * tmp=array[i+1];
array[i+1]=array[i];
array[i]=tmp;

Comment: I replace it with simple swap(array[i], array[i+1]);

Comment: Congratulations! If the problem has been solved, would you please select this one as the "Answer" to settle this question item.